# Regular Expression for XXXXXX.XX formatted number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression with this format: `XXXXXX.XX`
There can be less than 6 digits, and the `.XX` part should be optional.

```
function checkFormat(el) {
    var ex = new RegExp(/ ^[0-9]{1,6}([.][0-9]{1,2})$/);
    var valid = ex.test(el.value);
    return valid;
}
```

What should be the right regular expression?

Comment: Is `1234.5` allowed or shoudl it always have two digits if it has a dot e.g. `1234.50` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "?" to make the "( )" part optional, and I replace the `[.]` by `\.` and `[0-9]` by `\d`

```
/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: dot inside a character class doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: I know, and I just replaced the character class by an escaped dot

Answer (score 2):

Make the `.` and last `2` digits optional `(?:\.[\d]{2})?`, i.e.:

```
/^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{2})?$/
```

```js
function checkFormat(el) {
    var ex = new RegExp(/^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/);
    var valid = ex.test(el);
    return valid;
}

document.write("12345 " + checkFormat(12345)+"<br>");
document.write("12345.002 " + checkFormat(12345.002)+"<br>");
document.write("12345.00 " +  checkFormat(12345.00)+"<br>");
document.write("123455555 " + checkFormat(123455555)+"<br>");
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT2rR0/1)